# How to make Class function repeat it self in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to make this code repeat it self so my program never closes.

```
    import os
    print "Unesite navedene informacije za ucenika"
    class Ucenik1(object):
      """docstring for Ucenik1"""
        def __init__(self,  ime, prezime, razred, godiste, struka, dodatne_info):

             self.ime = ime
             self.prezime = prezime
             self.razred = razred
             self.godiste = godiste
             self.struka = struka,
             self.dodatne_info = dodatne_info

        def informacije_ucenika(self):
            my_list = [self.ime , 
                       self.prezime, 
                       self.razred, 
                       self.godiste, 
                       self.struka,
                       self.dodatne_info
               ]
         list = open("text.txt", "w")
         for item in my_list:
             list.write(str(item) + "\n")

         list.close()
         os.rename("text.txt", self.ime)

ucenici1 = Ucenik1(raw_input(str("Unesite ime")), raw_input(str("Unesite             prezime")), raw_input(str("Unesite razred")), raw_input(str("Unesite godiste")),                    raw_input(str("Unesite struku")), raw_input(str("Unesite dodatne informacije")))

ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
```

It's basicly a program that takes informations about students and stores them into file.
It works fine but I would like to make it repeat it self so you don't have to run .exe every time u want to make one file.
Online I found that I could use while loop but I could not make it work for class.
note: There are some indentation errors here but its all good in my editor

Comment: What about `while True: Ucenik1(...)`?

Comment: To write it above class Ucenik1(object) ?

Comment: btw, you should avoid using `list` as a variable name

Comment: @FilipCrnogorac Exactly as I wrote it: instead of `ucenici1 = Ucenik1(...)` use `while True: Ucenik1(...)`.

Comment: Ok I changed it, thank you.

Comment: @a_guest Ok I will try now.

Comment: @a_guest It is working but I can't put  "ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()" into loop cuz of identation error, so it's never writing new file with informations I  input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what part of code do you want to repeat.
If you want to add a student and save it into file infinitely,you should probably put the

```
while True:
    ucenici1 = Ucenik1(...)
    ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
```

With respect to the indentation - spacing for statements under while loop (editors like PyCharm should do that for you if you write it out; usually it's four spaces or use TAB instead). So the last two statements will repeat themselves.

Comment: It results in  "Sorry: IndentationError: ('unindent does not match any outer indentation level'"

Comment: I've already edited the answer. Try writing the while loop manually and then adjust statements under it.. Just like in the `for` loop. Basically it just has problems with spaces -too few/many.

Comment: @h4nek Using block code (via the `{}` button) will fix that issue. Using ` doesn't work terribly well for multi-line code.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Edited that, thanks for the tip. And thanks OP for my first approved answer. :D Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question to wrap the lines of code that are running within a while loop (as you suspected was the solution).

```
while True:
    ucenici1 = Ucenik1(raw_input(str("Unesite ime")), raw_input(str("Unesite             prezime")), raw_input(str("Unesite razred")), raw_input(str("Unesite godiste")),                    raw_input(str("Unesite struku")), raw_input(str("Unesite dodatne informacije")))

    ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
```

There are many other improvements that could also be suggested, like not having to cast strings to strings using str, opening the file with the name you want, rather than renaming it, and not using list as a variable name as list is a python keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, but with a `while True` loop:

```
import os
print "Unesite navedene informacije za ucenika"
class Ucenik1(object):
  """docstring for Ucenik1"""
    def __init__(self,  ime, prezime, razred, godiste, struka, dodatne_info):

         self.ime = ime
         self.prezime = prezime
         self.razred = razred
         self.godiste = godiste
         self.struka = struka,
         self.dodatne_info = dodatne_info

    def informacije_ucenika(self):
        my_list = [self.ime , 
                   self.prezime, 
                   self.razred, 
                   self.godiste, 
                   self.struka,
                   self.dodatne_info
           ]
     list = open("text.txt", "w")
     for item in my_list:
         list.write(str(item) + "\n")

     list.close()
     os.rename("text.txt", self.ime)

while True:
    ucenici1 = Ucenik1(raw_input(str("Unesite ime")), raw_input(str("Unesite             prezime")), raw_input(str("Unesite razred")), raw_input(str("Unesite godiste")),                    raw_input(str("Unesite struku")), raw_input(str("Unesite dodatne informacije")))

    ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
```

Comment: while True:
    ucenici1 = Ucenik1(raw_input(str("Unesite ime")), raw_input(str("Unesite             prezime")), raw_input(str("Unesite razred")), raw_input(str("Unesite godiste")),                    raw_input(str("Unesite struku")), raw_input(str("Unesite dodatne informacije")))

    ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()  causes    ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    ucenici1 = Ucenik1(raw_input(str("Unesite ime")), raw_input(str("Unesite             prezime")), raw_input(str("Unesite razred")), raw_input(str("Unesite godiste")),                    raw_input(str("Unesite struku")), raw_input(str("Unesite dodatne informacije")))

    ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
```

causes

ucenici1.informacije_ucenika()
                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: This is caused by indentation problems. Python indentation is important and we can't really help you with that until you show us what is exactly in your code (you note that "There are some indentation errors here but its all good in my editor"). Are you sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces?